# zend debugger won't continue for other pages

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, zend-framework

The Zend debugger is working for single pages in my Eclipse set up. Breakpoints in that PHP page work fine but I can't get the debugger to not terminate after the first page loads. My debugger configuration:

```
x Open in browser
   Start Debug from: <my index page>
      x Continue Debug from this page
```

Have tried:

- Clearing and resetting breakpoints
- List item
- Restarting eclipse
- Getting latest PDT